# Getting error building Apple Core Data Tutorial using ARC

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have been struggling with Core Data *sigh* so I decided to work this [this Apple Core Data tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/01_StartingOut.html).  I am at the point in the tutorial where it asks me to build the project I have put together so far.  So I am presently [right here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/02_RootViewController.html) in the tutorial.  When I am building the project I am getting the following error:

`Type of property 'managedObjectContext' ('NSManagedObjectContext *') does not match type of ivar 'managedObjectContext' ('MSManagedObject *__strong')`

RootViewController.m

`Ivar is declared here`

That's what I am getting in error window.

Here are what my files look like,

RootViewController.h http://pastie.org/4111206

RootViewController.m http://pastie.org/4111216

AppDelegate.h http://pastie.org/4111222

AppDelegate.m http://pastie.org/4111227

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ivar is declared incorrectly.  In RootViewController.h,

```
NSManagedObject *managedObjectContext;
```

should be written, as the error complains,

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

And actually, with the modern run-time, for quite a while it's been unnecessary (and usually ill-advised) to explicitly declare backing ivars for `@synthesize`'d properties.  So you can just delete the ivar line entirely and let the compiler make an ivar for you.

Comment: thanks for pointing that for me.  when i get home i will give what you say a try, and then mark the question as answered.  appreciate the well written reply.

Comment: @Chris My pleasure, let me know if you run into any issues.  (That sounds like fairly old sample code, so it wouldn't surprise me if there are some other issues lying in wait.)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is explaining it already.
You have an ivar managedObjectContext of class NSManagedObject (thats your mistake).

The compiler can't synthesize the property managedObjectContext because you have an ivar of the same name, but different class.

Rename the ivar and change the synthesize line:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
```